# Assessing the effect of an intervention on a time series (in R): terrible Ljung-Box p-values

Tags: r, arima, intervention-analysis

I am trying to test the effect on the heat flux between indoors and outdoors before and after removing insulation.

Briefly, I have 26 sensors on a wall, measuring heat flow between indoors and outdoors over a number of days. The wall was part of a real world experimental setup so that the insulation on the wall was removed halfway through the experiment.  What I care about is to have a measure of the effect of the removal of the insulation (I am not interested in any form of forecasting).  I am exploring the use of a SARIMA/ARIMAX models with one regressor because, aside from the removal of the insulation, the heat flow between indoors and outdoors was affected by daily cyclical and random environmental effects (heating on or off, daily temperature changes, wind, etc).  Here I will present that data and analysis of one sensor.  My data has been collected hourly, and I have transformed the variable ‘insulated’ ‘not insulated’ as a factor of 0s and 1s as indicator.

```
heat.flux = c(8.677048,6.558642,5.920314,5.583614,5.373176,5.253928,4.938272,7.358305,9.743266,10.46577,11.06201,10.90067,11.49691,13.15236,12.10017,10.60606,10.45875,10.03788,9.588945,9.287318,8.578844,8.024691,10.26936,11.8757,10.20623,8.634961,8.305275,8.101852,8.12991,7.947531,7.814254,10.40264,13.08221,14.3729,14.94809,15.08838,15.20763,15.75477,14.57632,12.79461,11.97391,10.97082,10.33249,9.701178,9.715208,9.083895,10.63412,12.07912,9.736251,7.638889,6.453423,5.983446,5.499439,5.099607,4.70679,6.972503,9.259259,9.981762,10.24832,10.17116,10.27637,10.27637,9.546857,7.568743,7.168911,6.867284,6.705948,6.916386,8.319304,8.424523,11.41274,13.52413,11.70034,9.532828,8.957632,9.07688,9.694164,9.301347,9.048822,12.28255,14.95511,15.22868,15.24972,15.12346,15.08838,15.17256,13.68547,12.18434,12.1633,12.13524,11.81257,11.58109,11.44781,11.27946,13.87486,15.92312,14.07828,11.90376,10.46577,9.518799,8.978676,8.803311,8.684063,11.65123,14.39394,15.69865,16.61756,16.828,16.83502,16.16863,14.23962,12.19837,12.09315,11.5881,11.20932,10.50786,10.59203,10.64815,13.51712,15.71268,13.92396,12.10718,12.2615,11.65123,11.05499,10.31846,9.834456,12.9349,15.41807,15.78283,15.8179,16.11953,15.95118,15.63552,13.1243,11.22334,10.21324,8.705107,7.526655,6.15881,5.30303,5.597643,8.599888,11.17424,9.631033,8.038721,7.638889,7.203984,7.161897,6.76908,6.888328,9.518799,12.40881,13.21549,14.28872,14.43603,14.8078,14.81481,13.60129,12.59119,11.86167,11.91779,11.73541,12.04405,11.51796,11.74242,13.7486,15.85999,14.84989,12.63328,10.68322,9.343434,8.592873,8.333333,8.445567,10.97783,13.82576,15.12346,16.58249,17.61364,18.30808,19.10774,17.97138,16.62458,15.867,16.07744,15.63552,16.0073,15.42508,15.01122,17.10157,18.94641,22.44669,18.94641,16.01431,14.55527,13.88889,12.77357,11.66526,12.46493,15.41807,16.75786,17.27694,17.03143,16.84905,16.828,16.02834,16.35802,16.04237,15.03928,14.00112,14.1344,13.86785,13.99411,15.30584,18.20286,19.49355,16.16162,14.05022,12.05107,12.27553,13.01207,12.5491,13.72054,16.91218,18.62374,18.79209,20.80527,19.50758,20.18799,20.63692,18.49747,17.25589,17.38215,18.40629,18.60269,19.12177,18.66582,21.09989,24.45286,26.71156,23.54798,20.01964,17.98541,14.83586,14.31678,15.15152,15.30584,17.95735,19.71801,20.30724,20.19501,20.2862,20.1459,20.10382,18.20988,16.54742,15.22868,13.96605,12.71044,11.61616,10.71829,12.12121,14.77273,14.04321,12.44388,10.94978,10.2413,9.708193,9.638047,9.322391,11.27245,14.24663,14.77273,14.75168,14.92705,15.47419,15.48822,14.73765,13.68547,12.65432,12.35269,12.34568,12.32464,12.7385,12.84371,14.16947,17.34007,17.09456,15.0954,13.40488,11.70735,10.8165,10.64815,12.01599,13.55219,16.7298,17.45932,17.61364,19.58474,20.02666,19.79517,19.38833,17.32604,16.11953,15.62851,15.01122,14.70258,14.5693,14.35887,16.28086,18.69388,18.92536,16.56846,15.97222,13.34877,12.81566,12.04405,13.23653,14.1835,16.75786,17.55752,17.98541,18.85522,18.8482,19.02357,18.96044,17.31201,15.42508,14.38692,13.57323,12.36672,12.03002,11.41274,13.15236,15.88103,14.66049,12.8858,11.67228,11.03395,9.399551,8.375421,8.073793,10.6271,13.57323,13.61532,14.31678,14.73765,15.08838,15.62149,16.6807,15.28479,14.07127,13.14534,12.61223,12.57015,12.02301,12.17031,14.33782,18.83418,20.45455,18.67985,18.40629,16.51235,14.45006,14.61841,15.20763,15.57941,18.06958,19.88636,20.51066,21.633,23.24635,24.28451,24.70539,24.19332,22.81145,21.97671,21.58389,21.3945,21.21212,20.89646,21.1069,23.86364)

insulation = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

First off, the time series plot of the heat flux is this (the red line is when the insulation is removed):

[image: Time series plot of heat flux]

Than this are the ACF and PACF plots of the same data:

[image: ACF and PACF of the data]

For my data, an `stl()` decomposition, run as `stl(ts(heat.flux, frequency = 24), 'period')`

shows a strong ‘seasonal’ (i.e daily) component and a trend in the series.

[image: STL of the data]

Firs off I am trying to determine the best parameters for a SARIMA or ARIMAX model so that I can get an estimation of the effect removing the insulation. Despite the fact I can produce the ACF and PACF plots there is no way I can figure out the proper orders, so I load the library `forecast` and I run:

```
library(forecast)
auto.arima(ts(heat.flux, frequency = 24), xreg = insulation, max.p = 10, max.q = 10, max.P = 10, max.Q = 10, stationary = F)
```

The reason why I do not specify a stationary model is because of the trend I see with `stl()` and because I assume an effect of removing the insulation.

from `auto.arima()` I get:

```
Series: ts(heat.flux, frequency = 24) 
ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,0,1)[24] with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1      ma2    sar1     sma1  intercept  carp.hour$interv
      1.9414  -0.9495  -0.7423  -0.1793  0.9717  -0.6009    11.2449            4.3338
s.e.  0.0231   0.0221   0.0570   0.0544  0.0104   0.0544     2.1075            0.5548

sigma^2 estimated as 0.4484:  log likelihood=-411.28
AIC=840.55   AICc=841.03   BIC=876.11
```

If I try to use the `TSA` package and use `arimax()` with those orders I get basically the same stuff:

```
library(TSA)
arimax(ts(heat.flux, frequency = 24), xreg = insulation, order = c(2,0,2), seasonal = list(order = c(1,0,1), frequency = 24))
Series: x 
ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,0,1)[24] with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1      ma2    sar1     sma1  intercept    xreg
      1.9414  -0.9495  -0.7423  -0.1793  0.9717  -0.6009    11.2449  4.3338
s.e.  0.0231   0.0221   0.0570   0.0544  0.0104   0.0544     2.1075  0.5548

sigma^2 estimated as 0.4484:  log likelihood=-411.28
AIC=838.55   AICc=839.03   BIC=874.11
```

And all is apparently well (Irrespective of the function I choose I get an estimate of the effect of the removal of the insulation and a se with it with is what I want).  Unfortunately, when I test the fit of this model with the function `sarima()` from the `astsa`package I get significant Ljung-Box p-values for all my sensors and for all the lags:

```
library(astsa)
sarima(ts(heat.flux, frequency = 24), p = 2, d = 0, q = 2, P =1, D = 0, Q = 1, S = 24, xreg = insulation)
$fit

Call:
stats::arima(x = xdata, order = c(p, d, q), seasonal = list(order = c(P, D, 
Q), period = S), xreg = xreg, optim.control = list(trace = trc, REPORT = 1, 
reltol = tol))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1      ma2    sar1     sma1  intercept    xreg
      1.9414  -0.9495  -0.7423  -0.1793  0.9717  -0.6009    11.2449  4.3338
s.e.  0.0231   0.0221   0.0570   0.0544  0.0104   0.0544     2.1075  0.5548

sigma^2 estimated as 0.4484:  log likelihood = -411.28,  aic = 840.55
```

but the plot that comes with is shows that at every single lag the Ljung-Box statistics is significant:

[image: SARIMA]

What is going on?  To sum it up:

1. which of these models is the most correct to estimate the effect of insulation?
2. why are the Ljung-Box p-values all significant?  I would have though that the ARIMA/ARIMAX/SARIMA would have sorted that issue
3. If the orders calculated by `auto.arima()` are the problem, how could I find them in a different way (which is computationally feasible and does not take days).

Finally, two notes.  I also have collected variables such as internal and external temperatures, windspeed, etc, but I would have though that integrating these in the model would be superfluous given the fact it is already an ARIMA model to start with.  Second, I am not at all wedded to this kind of analysis, but I am aware that a straightforward linear model would not be acceptable given the autocorrelation between the data points.

Comment: Looks like you have a cyclical pattern with a length of 69 in your data, do you know why this would be the case ?

Comment: That would be something happening every 2.875 days, which in my opinion is 100% spurious

Comment: Do you believe that there would be a second seasonal pattern?. Looking at the trend portion of stl, I do see a cyclical pattern.

Comment: With regards to your first question: all 3 models show the same effect of 4.3338, because you have used the same ARMA order in all 3 models. I'm not sure about your question. All 3 models are identical!

Comment: Concerning cyclical patterns, the cyclical temperature change during the day affects the heat flux, and so does th heating of the ouse that is on twice a day (morning and evening).  I am aware that the models are the same, but the issue is, `sarima` does give some diagnostics, and the Ljung-Box p-values are very worrying. Having said that is is difficult to figure out another way of finding the parameters for the model that does not use `auto.arima()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the functions you've used call `stats:::arima()` or something based on it, so they will return identical models given the same orders. You could get some of the same graphical output using `tsdiag()` applied to the object returned by `auto.arima()`.

The model has correlated residuals, which will make the standard errors on the coefficients biased, and the forecast prediction intervals biased. It will not, however, bias the point forecasts themselves or the regression coefficient estimates. If your primary interest is in the coefficient for insulation, then what you have is ok although the standard error is incorrect.

You could ask auto.arima() to try harder by using `stepwise=FALSE` and `approximation=FALSE`. However, I suggest you reduce the values of `max.P` and `max.Q` to 2 (the defaults). The order selection will take a long time -- probably at least 20 minutes -- for a series that long with these settings.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your answer.  I notice that the Ljung-Box statistics are substantially better when I use `tsdiag()` on the results on `auto.arima()` -- there is a discrepancy with the Ljung Box results from `sarima()`, something I think I should flag up.  Also, I am just interested in the effect of insulation, but it would be useful to have a reasonable standard error -- I am presenting these results to people who are desperate for 'p-values' and I think I should give them at least some reasonable estimate of the uncertainty around the parameter.